# Permanent magnet brushed DC motor freewheeling

Tags: pwm, flyback, brushed-dc-motor

As a hobby project, I want to mount a permanent magnet (PM) brushed DC motor on a bike.

I've already asked a question about the PWM and half-bridge driving circuit for the motor and got a very useful reply. So I'm good about the electronics part.

What I'm wondering about is the actual mechanical behaviour of the motor, especially the possibility of freewheeling its shaft.

For example, if the motor is directly mechanically connected to the backwheel with a chain, can I stop accelerating but keep freewheeling forward by applying a 0% PWM duty cycle?

From what I've understood, PM DC motors must act as generators if freewheeled, and will either arc with open terminals or brake with shorted terminals. And when a 0% PWM duty cycle is applied, the flyback MOSFET is on (or the flyback diode) and the motor brakes.

Is there a way to freewheel the shaft of a PM DC motor? Or the only solution is to mechanically decouple the motor by using a freewheel ratchet or a clutch? I'll gladly take any real life e-bike design examples you might want to share.

I hope my question was clear and not too stupid.

[image]

Comment: It depends on what you actually mean by 0% duty cycle. An H-bridge has more degrees of freedom than PWMing between 0% and 100%. There is a difference between shorting the terminals to each other and having the terminals not connected. A generator whose wires are connected to nothing tries to power nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a 0% PWM duty cycle is applied, the **flyback MOSFET is on** (or the
> flyback diode) **and the motor brakes**.

Correct, but only when the 'flyback' MOSFET is turned on. To allow mechanical freewheeling you should keep the upper FET turned off and only apply PWM to the lower FET. The body diode inside the upper FET takes care of back-emf caused by winding inductance, so you don't have to worry about 'arcing'.

Turn PWM down to 0% and the bike will coast. Since the motor is going slower than it would under full power it can't generate enough voltage to do any damage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Please tell me if I have understood correctly : for mechanical freewheeling, I should turn off both MOSFETS and for electric braking I should turn on the flyback MOSFET only ?

Comment: There is one thing I don't quite grasp about half bridge using PWM : the high part of the PWM signal turns the drive MOSFET on while the low part turns the flyback MOSFET on. Let's say the PWM signal is 50% duty cycle, then half of the time the motor is electrically braking ? Isn't that counterproductive ? Or this helps in some way regenerating the magnetic fields ? But again the magnetic field is established and collapsed on every commutation of the brushes. Please tell me what I'm getting wrong here.

Comment: The motor's winding inductance keeps motor current going during PWM off period. During this time the motor winding is 'shorted', so current decays slowly because the L/R time constant is high. Provided the PWM frequency is high enough, motor current will be relatively smooth (ramping up during PWM on, down during PWM off) and the motor will get continuous torque. PWM reduces the effective motor voltage proportionally so it runs at lower speed. If the motor is going faster that this speed then its generator voltage will be higher so current reverses (going back into the battery) and it brakes.

Comment: So half-bridge PWM forces the motor to run at a speed proportional to the PWM, just like would happen on a lower battery voltage. Without half-bridge this doesn't happen because the current only decays until inductive back-emf voltage drops below the flyback diode's turn-on voltage. Then the motor is effectively disconnected until the next PWM on period. If the motor is going faster than the effective PWM voltage it draws no current and coasts, until it slows down enough that generator voltage drops below PWM voltage where it can start drawing current again.

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks!
So, with a half-bridge, if the motor is freewheeled at a generator voltage equivalent to 100% PWM (battery voltage), if I set the PWM duty cycle to 50%, energy will be stored in the inductance during the off periods and fed back into the battery during on periods ? So, if my battery is 24V and the motor is spun to generate 24V between its terminals, by using a 50% PWM half-bridge I can recharge the battery even though it's the same voltage ?
If I'm correct, what is then the "optimal" PWM value for regenerative braking ?

Comment: _"what is then the "optimal" PWM value for regenerative braking ?"_ - if you mean 'best % for maximum braking', it would be close to 0%. If you mean 'most efficient for regeneration' it would be the value that produces just enough braking to do what you want (eg. limit downhill speed, stop in a set distance). If the battery can't take it then things get more complicated. You can't recharge a full battery so if going downhill on a full charge you can't use regenerative braking and need to switch in a resistor to disippate the energy (or use mechanical brakes).

Comment: Would the hydraulic analogy of PWM regenerative braking be the hydraulic ram pump ? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_ram)
This pump allows you to pump water to a higher level using only the hydraulic power of a lower level source (no external work). This will move some water to a higher level but waste a fraction of the water proportional to the level difference between the source ant the output (the higher the output, the more water is wasted and the less is actually pushed up).

Comment: Is it kind of similar with regenerative braking ? The higher the battery voltage, the lower the PWM duty cycle needs to be to be able to keep filling the battery (and keep braking at the same time).
And therefore I'm guessing the lower the PWM duty cycle, the more energy is wasted.
And therefore, 0% duty cycle is maximum braking and 100% wasted energy.

Am I correct about all this or am I getting ahead of myself ?

Comment: Is that what you meant by "_'most efficient for regeneration' it would be the value that produces just enough braking to do what you want_" ? That the PMW duty cycle value that wastes the least energy while still allowing braking and regeneration is one that gives an effective battery voltage just below the generator voltage of the motor ?
For example, if my battery is at 75% charge (18V for a 24V battery) and my motor generates 10V, I'd need 55% (18V x 0.55 = 10V) or lower PMW duty cycle to start braking and regenerating ?

Comment: "Since the motor is going slower than it would under full power it can't generate enough voltage to do any damage." Unless you coast downhill, in which case you might go faster than possible under full power on level ground.

Answer (score 1):

the best freewheel you can get from a PM motor is when it is open circuit

> From what I've understood, PM DC motors must act as generators if freewheeled, and will either arc with open terminals or brake with shorted terminals. And when a 0% PWM duty cycle is applied, the flyback MOSFET is on (or the flyback diode) and the motor brakes.

It will only arc if you are going too fast for the motor controller to handle
otherwise the controller will have no problem with the voltage (because voltage is basically proportional to speed)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer!
I've added a half-bridge schematic to my question.
So if I want to freewheel the PM motor, I'd need to add, for example, a switch between the motor and the flywheel MOSFET to get an open circuit ? I'm sure this would make a lot of sparking but is it the correct general idea ?

Comment: It can arc at the moment commutator segments leave the brushes. This is low power (but high V) stuff, dealt with by snubbers and/or flyback diodes. But this answer is correct about the motor acting as generator, where the real power is.

Comment: true, you get that arcing when the motor has voltage on the terminals and is spinning. but it's no worse than when it's running.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! So if the circuit can handle the motor running at full speed, it will be able to handle the motor acting as generator when it is freewheeled since its speed should be lower than running speed anyways.

Comment: I have another question about the flyback diode : does it need to be rated for the peak/stall current of the motor or the current that will run through it will never reach such intensity ?
The motor I ultimately want to use has 100A peak current (I suppose it's equivalent to stall current) according to the data sheet. That is a huge amount of current and I was wondering how to handle it; could you give me some advice ? Does the PWM helps with that ? I guess the MOSFETs will have to be huge as well.

Comment: it should be rated for the current the motor driver is capable of.